# Responsive Bootstrap Wordpress Post

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Recently I've done this blog: http://bloganacastro.com/ and it's everything OK. But on mobile version I have a trouble.

If you access it on mobile, you can see that the posts column is less than total of the page. I've tried everything and can't solve this.

Hope someone could help.

Comment: On line 137 of style.css you have the rule width: 60%; I see this applied in all sizes of the window and seems to originate from the need to make space for the portrait image of the woman which shows at larger windows sizes. I would only apply that style once the width gets to a certain size using a media query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set a width to a bootstrap grid class. If you are using the Bootstrap's grid system **you shouldn't change** the width property to those classes.

```
.conteudo.col-lg-8 {
    margin-left: 4%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    width: 60%;
    margin-top: 6%;
}
```

I assume that you need to have `width: 60%;` so as a workaround you could put the above CSS to a media query so that it applies only in big screens, e.g.

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .conteudo.col-lg-8 {
        margin-left: 4%;
        margin-right: 2%;
        width: 60%;
        margin-top: 6%;
    }

}
```

Take a look [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries) on how Bootstrap handles various screen sizes and what media queries it uses.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm new at Bootstrap themes and really I need this width. I fixed with your media query. =)

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the wrong bootstrap classes. Upon inspection, `.conteudo.col-lg-8` has a 60% width. Remove it and you are golden